# VPN connection prevents the computer from sleeping - can I avoid that?

Tags: vpn, power-management

Most of the time, I need to have an active VPN connection when working from my home PC.

I've discovered, that if the VPN is active, and I leave the computer, the computer does not go to sleep automatically, as it should. If i disconnect VPN, it works.

Why is that ? How can I ensure that my PC can go into sleep mode automatically even with the VPN connection on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut is to set a timeout for VPN connection in properties... Usability of this approach depends on how fast you want to switch on the sleep-mode.

Comment: +1, I will experiment with this - One of the primary uses is Exchange mail and RDP connections though - so even though I am not at the computer, I am guessing that the connection will seldomly go idle - So I am hoping someone can post an answer that will allow the computer to go to sleep *while* the VPN is on.